# How can I get the result of variance formulation in Gaussian process classification

Tags: classification, variance, gaussian-process

As we can see equation (3.23) in the book "Gaussian processes for machine learning" (please see the uploaded image), why are there two terms in this equation? This equation is used in the Gaussian process classification with Laplace approximation.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The f is itself a random variable with density q. When drawing a sample of the predictive distribution of f*, we first draw an f according to to the q-density, and then we draw an f* given f according to the posterior process gaussian distribution.

See e.g. the law of total variance.